# Appending Streaming Data to Dataframe Efficiently

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a connection to an API from which I am streaming data
which looks like this:

```
#An example line of the output from the API:
{'tick': {'instrument': 'AUD_USD', 'bid': 0.74692
, 'time': '2015-07-09T07:42:48.127521Z', 'ask': 0.74709}}
```

I am taking this and putting it into a dataframe for processing as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('time','bid','ask')) 
for line in response.iter_lines(1):             
     if line:
        try:
            msg = json.loads(line.decode())     
            if "instrument" in msg or "tick" in msg: 
                x  = pd.DataFrame([[msg['tick']['time'],msg['tick']['bid'],msg['tick']['ask']]], columns=('time','bid','ask'))
                df = df.append(x, ignore_index=True) 
        except Exception as e:
            print("Caught exception when converting message into json\n" + str(e))
```

My question is, is  there a more efficient way to get the data into 
the dataframe than in the above? However if there is a totally different way of doing this, then please do enlighten me!

I am especially suspicious of this line:

```
x  = pd.DataFrame([[msg['tick']['time'],msg['tick']['bid'],msg['tick']['ask']]], columns=('time','bid','ask'))
```

As I imagine getting dictionary info out could be more efficient.

Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cast your dict as a DataFrame in  order to append, you can pass the dictionary directly to `append` like this:

```
df = df.append(msg['tick'],ignore_index=True)
```

If you want to load them all in one batch, you could clean the responses with a list comprehension to keep only entries with the right keys, and then pass this in to `append` (you won't be able to skip individual exceptions though.)

```
response_cleaned = [{'time': msg['tick']['time'],
                     'bid': msg['tick']['bid'],
                     'ask': msg['tick']['ask']} 
               for msg in response 
               if 'tick' in msg 
               and 'ask' in msg['tick'] 
               and 'time' in msg['tick'] 
               and 'bid' in msg['tick']]

print("{} bad records recieved".format(len(response) - len(response_cleaned)))

df = df.append(response_cleaned)
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it's great to know I can append directly  - although how would I do this without brining all the fields back from msg? As I would like to exclude the 'instrument' field from the dataframe

Comment: ah didn't notice that it was adding the other column! i've updated my answer to just pick out the columns you want in the list comprehension.

Comment: That's visibly improved the stream speed, thanks heaps!